# Applescript Shell Script

Tags: bash, terminal, applescript

This works in Terminal

```
sudo npm install ios-sim -g
```

so why does this not work in AppleScript:

```
do shell script "cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm;" & "install ios-sim - g" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after "npm" and try.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the same command and you're using different arguments:

```
npm install ios-sim -g
^^^                 ^^
```

versus

```
install ios-sim - g
^^^^^^^         ^ ^
```

Answer (score -1):

Could be a formatting issue, add a space after the semi-colon and remove the space on the -g arg.

eg,

```
do shell script "cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm; " & "install ios-sim -g" with administrator privileges
```

Failing this, let us know what the result and/or error is in Applescript Editor.

Comment: I'm Getting this error     `error "install: ios-sim: No such file or directory" number 71`@adamh

Comment: does, do shell script "npm install ios-sim -g" work? Looks like you are browsing to a directory with a similar name to the command.